# Why no type conversion warning?

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, clang

I have the following snippet of C code, with -Wconversion enabled in Clang:

```
uint8_t num_ch = get_num_channels();
uint64_t test_mask = 1 << num_ch;
```

I was hoping this would throw a warning of some sort, since 1 is an implicit "signed int" and then getting assigned to a uint64_t, but the compiler did not complain :(

What am I missing?

Comment: Is `num_ch` constant? Anyway, the possible issue here is not type conversion, but shifting a signed `int`.

Comment: another issue is that even 1U << 40 will not also do what you expext

Comment: Worse than that - it doesn't even complain when you actually do shift a negative value: https://www.godbolt.org/z/eh6v9Y

Comment: Interesting! MSVC gives: **warning C4365: 'initializing': conversion from 'int' to 'uint64_t', signed/unsigned mismatch**. (I've declared: `uint64_t num_ch = 3;`). It also gives: **warning C4334: '<<': result of 32-bit shift implicitly converted to 64 bits (was 64-bit shift intended?)**.

Comment: Actually a very interesting question. I tried both `unsigned int x = 1 << 5;` and `int x = 1 << 5;` and neither gave me a warning

Comment: Might be time to ask which version of Clang and which flags were passed in.

Comment: gcc 4.8.5 with `-Wconversion` warns on this.

Comment: Can you show us the definition of `get_num_channels()`?

Comment: get_num_channels is a hardware-register read.

Comment: Playing around with clang-cl! Feel free to join in [this chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220593/discussion-between-anastaciu-and-adrian-mole), rather than bloating the comments section.

Comment: Even more baffling: https://godbolt.org/z/Mv6rYP

Comment: @TheLoneJoker, gcc 10 also does not trigger the warning but 9.3 does, https://godbolt.org/z/r8r3o7, at this point I give up, maybe tomorrow. Good luck.

Comment: Yes.. I am seeing the same behavior: https://godbolt.org/z/34edoE

Thanks for the help.

Comment: get_num_channels can be thought of similar to be a call to rand()

Comment: What version of clang are you using, and on what OS/version?

Answer (score 5):

> *Why no type conversion warning?*

Short answer: Because of a defect (some might even call it a bug) in the version of clang/LLVM that you are using.

**Discussion/Explanation/Reasoning**

The issue stems from the evaluation of a bit-shift expression, `s << u`, where `s` is a *signed* integer type and `u` is an *unsigned* type. Now, according to [this C11 Draft Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (bolding mine):

> **6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators**
>  ...
>  3 The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The **type of the result** is that
> of the promoted **left** operand.

Which means that the result of the expression is a *signed integer*. Henceforth, I should point out, I am using (and assuming) a platform that uses a 32-bit 'basic' `int` type. Note also that an *integer constant* without the `u` suffix is a *signed* type.

*Note: Although I don't have access to the OP's embedded system, nor to a local GCC compiler, I can nevertheless reproduce the issue using the **clang-cl** compiler provided in the latest version of Visual Studio 2019 (16.7.2 - I'll add the clang version when I've found out what it is).*

The following code ***does*** generate the expected warning (in fact, *two* warnings, as shown):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    uint64_t test_mask = 1 << (uint8_t)(31); // Warnings here, as expected.
    printf("%016llX\n", test_mask);
    return 0;
}
```

Warnings:

> warning : signed shift result (0x80000000) sets the sign bit of the
> shift expression's type ('int') and becomes negative
> [-Wshift-sign-overflow]
> warning : implicit conversion changes
> signedness: 'int' to 'uint64_t' (aka 'unsigned long long')
> [-Wsign-conversion]

Furthermore, the output of the `printf` call is `FFFFFFFF80000000`, which shows why the warning is important: the bit-shift (on a 32-bit `int`) has produced a negative value, which is then sign-extended when promoted to 64-bits - thus 'corrupting' the intended/expected result (which will be `0000000080000000` if the literal `1` is simply changed to `1u`, thus avoiding the sign-extension).

However! If a *very minor* (some might even say *insignificant*) change is made to the code, changing the literal (constant) right-hand operand of the bit-shift to an *exactly equivalent* variable, as shown in the code below, then the warnings from **clang-cl** vanish (but the output remains 'corrupted' - so the operations performed are the same).

```c
int main()
{
    uint8_t num_ch = 31;
    uint64_t test_mask = 1 << num_ch; // No warning here!
    printf("%016llX\n", test_mask);
    return 0;
}
```

Possibly not the most helpful answer - but what more can be done, other than reporting the issue to the folks at LLVM? I would *definitely* file such a report, because the code as posted by the OP could cause some serious issues that *should* be detected and indicated by a compiler with full warnings enabled (MSVC warns even for the second code snippet).

Comment: It sure seems to be a bug, but more doubts arise when you consider that gcc removed the warning in the upgraded 10 version whereas the 9.3 version still emits it https://godbolt.org/z/33M4dn